# Kill a running thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

What happens if we forcefully kill a running thread

I have a thread namely `RecordThread()` which calls some complex and time consuming functions. In these functions I am using *try-catch* blocks, allocating and deallocation memory and using critical section variables etc.

like

```
  void RecordThread()
  {
    AddRecord();
    FindRecord();
    DeleteRecord();
    // ...
    ExitThread(0);
   }
```

After creating this thread, I am immediately killing it before the thread completes its execution. In this case what happens if the thread is forcefully killed? Do the internal functions (`AddRecord`, `DeleteRecord`) complete their execution after we killed the thread?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> After creating this thread, I am immediately killing it before the thread completes its execution.

I assume you mean you are using `TerminateThread()` in the following fashion:

```
HANDLE thread = CreateThread(...);

// ...
// short pause or other action?
// ...

TerminateThread(thread, 0); // Dangerous source of errors!
CloseHandle(thread);
```

If that is the case, then no, the thread executing `RecordThread()` will be stopped exactly where it is at the time that the other thread calls `TerminateThread()`.  As per the notes in the [`TerminateThread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation, this exact point is somewhat random and depends on complex timing issues which are out of your control.  This implies that you can't handle proper cleanup inside a thread and thus, [you should rarely, if ever, kill a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4149210/313063).

The proper way to request the thread to finish is by using `WaitForSingleObject()` like so:

```
HANDLE thread = CreateThread(...);

// ...
// some other action?
// ...

// you can pass a short timeout instead and kill the thread if it hasn't
// completed when the timeout expires.
WaitForSingleObject(thread, INFINITE);
CloseHandle(thread);
```

Comment: To make it more explicit: `TerminateThread` can kill your thread in the middle of an `i++` statement. It doesn't try to look for "nice" points such as function calls.

Comment: Note that POSIX is much different from Win32 API in this respect (by default, unless the thread modified its cancellation settings), it will indeed only kill your thread at a cancellation point. So apart from being dangerous, it's not even equally dangerous everywhere, and thus not "portable" :-)

Comment: If it's not obvious from the other comments, some more reasons why you should never use TerminateThread: [Windows started picking up the really big pieces of TerminateThread garbage on the sidewalk, but it's still garbage on the sidewalk](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2015/08/14/10635157.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682659%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> ExitThread is the preferred method of exiting a thread in C code. However, in C++ code, the thread is exited **before any destructors can be called** or any other automatic cleanup can be performed. Therefore, in C++ code, you should return from your thread function.

However the function calls will of course be completed because they're called before the ExitThread().

Comment: What if they don't have enough time to complete?

Comment: @sharptooth like in single-threaded code, sequential consistency guarantees that all the lines before ExitThread() will complete.

Answer (score 3):

killing thread is the last resort - as Andre stated it leaves data in unknown state, you should never do that if thread works on shared object. Better choices are to notify thread to finish work by:

-using global *volatile* (important) variable which is changed only by main thread and tested by workers
-using *signal* type synchronization objects (mainly Events) also set by main thread and tested by workers

Answer (score 1):

example of Thread that works well:

```
definition in *.h ------------------------------------

DWORD WINAPI Th_EspectroIF(LPVOID lpData);

CThread th_espectro(Th_EspectroIF);

use in *.cc -----------------------------------

DWORD WINAPI Th_EspectroIF(LPVOID lpData)
{

//Your code...

th_espectro.Stop(true);//stop this Thread 

}
```

call the Thread with: **th_espectro.Start();**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged. How is this answer different from or better than previous answers?