# How to safely call TerminateThread and FreeLibrary (WinAPI, C++)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I used to unload an injected library by calling `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` from a thread that was created using `CreateThread`.

The need to unload the library from a different thread rendered this approach impossible. Now I'm using `TerminateThread` (as it doesn't terminate the thread it's called from, but the one that is passed) and `FreeLibrary` separately. However as the WinAPI docs suggest this creates a "race condition" and crashes the process. Is there any way to fix this?

Old code:

```
HMODULE g_hModule{ NULL };

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD fwdReason, LPVOID lpReserved) {
    g_hModule = hModule;
    if (fwdReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hModule);
        CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)main, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    return TRUE;
}

void Unload(int nExitCode) {
    FreeLibraryAndExitThread(g_hModule, (DWORD)nExitCode);
}
```

New code:

```
HMODULE g_hModule{ NULL };
HANDLE g_hThread{ NULL };

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD fwdReason, LPVOID lpReserved) {
    g_hModule = hModule;
    if (fwdReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hModule);
        g_hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)main, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    return TRUE;
}

void Unload(int nExitCode) {
    TerminateThread(g_hThread, (DWORD)nExitCode);
    FreeLibrary(g_hModule);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kill a running thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737417/kill-a-running-thread) In any case, search for "[c++] terminate thread" here and you will find lots of info. Understand the implications of terminating a thread before pursuing this path any further.

Comment: Short answer: no there isn't. C++ does not work this way. Thread termination via any means other than returning from the original thread function is undefined behavior. `TerminateThread` does not have well-defined behavior with C++ code. It is not meant to be used with C++ code.

Comment: new code wrong in all case and senseless. `TerminateThread` - you terminate the **self** thread. `FreeLibrary` is never called. no sense create thread for just terminate it (even not exit correct). old code is look like correct (assume `main == Unload` and wrong signature for unload)

Comment: in the old code `Unload` is called from `main` (the thread created by `CreateThread`) in the new one it is called from a separate thread. this is why i believe `FreeLibrary` should run

Comment: `ULONG WINAPI Unload(PVOID) { FreeLibraryAndExitThread((HMODULE)&__ImageBase, 0);` and `CreateThread(0, 0, Unload, 0, 0, 0);` this is how code need look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to terminate a thread safely, in C++ especially, is to have that thread return from the function passed to `CreateThread`.  This is usually done by setting (say) an `atomic<bool>` that the thread tests regularly to see if it should exit.  You might also use a condition variable (or the Win32 equivalent) to wake the thread up, rather than busy-looping.

`TerminateThread` is deadly dangerous as, for example, the thread might be holding some kind of critical lock (perhaps the one used by `malloc`) at the time and that would hang the rest of your app.  It should never have been provided in the Win32 API in the first place and you should not use it.

Comment: but how `TerminateThread` related to question ? question about how dereference dll from this dll.

Comment: OP want unload dll. absolute not related to terminatethread