# Closing/Exiting Thread from Main Thread based on condition in Windows C

Tags: c, multithreading

I am very new to C, and am learning the Windows threading API.

I have a toy program where I create a thread that toggles the volume key on my computer every 5 seconds. However, every 10 seconds I'd like to turn the thread off, next 10 seconds, turn it back on, indefinitely.

It seems to not give the expected behavior (volume_loop keeps running) after the if/else cases run, so I imagine I am not properly killing my threads. I'm trying to figure out the proper way to kill a thread based on a condition from my main thread.

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define SLEEP_TIME 5000 // 5 seconds

// global struct to hold thread state
struct thread_state {
        BOOL running;
};
struct thread_state ts = {.running=TRUE};

DWORD WINAPI volume_loop(void *data)
{
        unsigned int times_pressed = 0;
        while (1) {
                INPUT ip;
                ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;

                // sleep for 4 minutes & 50 seconds
                printf("sleeping for %ums\n", SLEEP_TIME);
                Sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
                times_pressed++;

                ip.ki.wScan = 0;
                ip.ki.time = 0;
                ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

                // press volume up
                ip.ki.wVk = VK_VOLUME_UP;
                ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
                printf("pressing volume up/down for the %u(st)(th)(rd) time !\n", times_pressed);
                SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

                // key release volume up
                ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
                SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

                Sleep(250);

                ip.ki.wVk = VK_VOLUME_DOWN;
                ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
                SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

                // key release volume down
                ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
                SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
        }
}

int main()
{

        // create thread
        HANDLE volume_h_thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, volume_loop, NULL, 0, NULL);
        if (volume_h_thread == NULL) {
                return 1;
        }

        while (1) {
                Sleep(10000);
                if (ts.running) {
                        puts("turning thread off!");
                        /* ExitThread(volume_h_thread); // incompatible pointer to integer conversion? */
                        CloseHandle(volume_h_thread);
                        ts.running = FALSE;
                } else {
                        puts("turning thread on!");
                        volume_h_thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, volume_loop, NULL, 0, NULL);
                        ts.running = TRUE;
                }
        }

        // wait for thread
        WaitForSingleObject(volume_h_thread, INFINITE);

        // close thread
        CloseHandle(volume_h_thread);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `CloseHandle` doesn't stop the thread. It is explicitly noted in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-closehandle): "Closing a thread handle does not terminate the associated thread or remove the thread object.". You may kill the thread with `TerminateThread`, but this is highly discouraged: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737417/kill-a-running-thread

Comment: @Tsyvarev I understand that, but I am looking for the "non discouraged way" to close a thread. I looked up the docs for ```ExitThread()``` and ```TerminateThread``` but they all seemed to not do what I am looking for.

Comment: Would such way exist, it will be noted in the answers to the [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737417/kill-a-running-thread), don't you think so? What is a reason to ask a question, which has already been asked and answered?