# UIBarButtonItem after animating disappears

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibarbuttonitem, uiactivityindicatorview

I have the UIBarButtonItem (configurated in interface builder). If a user click this button, the "heavy process" will be started and for better user experience I want to change this button with (UIActivityIndicatorView). I do it in the following way:

```
    self.indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];   
    indicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self.heavyBarButton initWithCustomView:self.indicator];

    [self.indicator startAnimating];

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(animateHeavyProcess) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

animateHeavyProcess:

```
     [self heavyProcess];
     [self.indicator stopAnimating];
     UIBarButtonItem *originalButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"maximize.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(startProcessClick:)];
     self.heavyBarButton = originalButton;
     [originalButton release];
```

**What happens:** after a user clicks the BarButton animation will be started and after processing button disappears. However, **I want** that the original button will be shown again.

Comment: Where Are you getting issue?what is your issue?your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

what if you use Grand Central Dispatch for the heavy process? I would think it's more convenient. But remember that you can not use any of the UI in that block. Here is an example: [iphone ios running in separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869217/iphone-ios-running-in-separate-thread)

Answer (score 0):

You should not be doing UI updates in a secondary thread; calls to UIKit should be on the main thread.

You can split out the UI updating part of your code:

```
- (void)restoreBarButtonItem
{
  [self.indicator stopAnimating];
  UIBarButtonItem *originalButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
     initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"maximize.png"]
     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
     target:self
     action:@selector(startProcessClick:)];
  self.heavyBarButton = originalButton;
  [originalButton release];
}
```

And then in your heavy process (running on the secondary thread) just call this new UI update method on the main thread:

```
- (void)animateHeavyProcess
{
  [self heavyProcess];
  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(restoreBarButtonItem:)
    withObject:nil
    waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use UIToolbar's setItems:animated: method to replace buttons.