# asynchronous sounds in iphone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I use the following code to play the sounds in my app, but the problem is that it slows down the app. How can I make the sounds happen asynchronously without slowing down the actions?

```
SystemSoundID soundID;
NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: _sound ofType:@ "wav"];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile], &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

Comment: try to execute the code in background thread ? See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3869355/188331

Answer (score 1):

Do the AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID  during app initialization, or at some other point ahead of time when the user can expect/accept a little lag.  It can be performed in the background, but the sound can't be played until it's finished.

[AudioServicesPlaySystemSound is asynchronous already.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html)

In other words, to demonstrate how do the init early, appDidFinishLaunching is the earliest opportunity.  Make your sounds available to other parts of the app with a public property...

```
// AppDelegate.h, add this inside the @interface
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *sounds;

// AppDelegate.m
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSMutableArray *tempSounds = [NSMutableArray array];

    SystemSoundID soundID0;
    // you need to initialize _sound0, _sound1, etc. as your resource names
    NSString *soundFile0 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: _sound0 ofType:@ "wav"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile0], &soundID0);

    [tempSounds addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:soundID0]];

    SystemSoundID soundID1;
    NSString *soundFile1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: _sound1 ofType:@ "wav"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile1], &soundID1);

    // SystemSoundID is an int type, so we wrap it in an NSNumber to keep in the array
    [tempSounds addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:soundID1]];

    self.sounds = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempSounds];

    // do anything else you do for app init here

    return YES;
}
```

Then in SomeViewController.m ...

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

// when you want to play a sound (the first one at index 0 in this e.g.)
NSArray *sounds = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).sounds;

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound([sounds[0] intValue]);
```

Comment: As early as appDidFinishLaunching.  I realize that might be a pain, since you'd then need to convey that soundID to the view controller that uses it.  But just to see if it feels right speed-wise, try it there first to see if it's good (make soundID a public property on your appDelegate, then get it like: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].soundID;

Comment: but what if I have different sounds throughout the view controller?

Comment: Just to get it working, use the same sound in each place.  If you find the speed acceptable, you can change it to an NSArray of soundIDs.